# getting detail country name and country code of a given phone number

Tags: java, android, telephony, country-codes, libphonenumber

I able to detect incoming calls in android but problem is that I want to know to the country code of that phone number so that I can analyze whether it is a national or international number. I know about [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) 
but It needs to know region code before hand to get the country code as shown in the example

```
String swissNumberStr = "044 668 18 00";
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
try {
  PhoneNumber swissNumberProto = phoneUtil.parse(swissNumberStr, "CH");
} catch (NumberParseException e) {
  System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString());
}
```

it already knows to put `"CH"` as a parameter. but we don't know if the number is to known to us then how we can analyze that number.

Answer (score 4):

As long as it is not a regional number (in which case it is just a plain number and no lib in this world could determine where it is from) you can specify `"ZZ"` or `null` for the second parameter of `parse`.

This is what the [documentation](http://javadox.com/com.googlecode.libphonenumber/libphonenumber/5.9/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberUtil.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) says:

> region that we are expecting the number to be from. This is only used
>   if the number being parsed is not written in international format. The
>   country_code for the number in this case would be stored as that of
>   the default region supplied. If the number is guaranteed to start with
>   a '+' followed by the country calling code, then "ZZ" or null can be
>   supplied.

After you where able to create an instace of `PhoneNumber` you can simply call `getRegionCodeForNumber` as shown below.

```
String swissNumberStr = "044 668 18 00";
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
try {
   PhoneNumber numberProto = phoneUtil.parse(swissNumberStr, "ZZ");
   System.out.println(phoneUtil.getRegionCodeForNumber(numberProto));
} catch (NumberParseException e) {
   System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: but there is not surety that number will start with '+', it can be 0321774444 or +92321774444 or 0092321774444

Comment: either the number starts with 00 or +, or you know the country in the first place. I don't think you can create a meaningful PhoneNumber instance otherwise.